# Images Not Displaying In Laravel 9 Under Some Circumstances

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I have a problem displaying images in my hosted Laravel 9 application.

The setup is as follows:

This line stores a user's profile picture:

`$formFields['profilepic'] = $file->store('profilepics', 'public');`

profilepic field data sample:
`'profilepics/jeG2zk5yfKIGhRx9KKHm9somelongname.png'`

The code below displays the picture in my views.

```
<img
    class="w-48 mr-6 mb-6"
    src="{{$tprofile->profilepic ? asset('storage/'.$tprofile->profilepic) : asset('images/no-image.png')}}"
    alt=""
/>
```

I have run  `'php artisan storage:link'` on my application's folder.

The setup works fine on my computer, but when I upload:

**1)** The existing (as uploaded from my PC) profile pictures display as desired in my views.

**2)** If I update the profile picture, it does not show the new picture in my view, using this code:

```
<img
    class="w-48 mr-6 mb-6"
    src="{{$tprofile->profilepic ? asset('storage/'.$tprofile->profilepic) : asset('images/no-image.png')}}"
    alt=""
/>
```

Changing the path to this also does not work:

`<?php $imageSrc = storage_path('app/public/' . $tprofile->profilepic); ?>`

**3)** If I generate a pdf that includes the picture using the code below,
it shows the updated picture, meaning the update was successful.

```
@if ($tprofile->profilepic)
    <?php $fullpath = storage_path('app/public/' . $tprofile->profilepic); ?>
    <img 
        class="w-48 mr-6 mb-6 mt-6"
        src="data:image/png;base64,
        <?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($fullpath)); ?>"
        width="150px"
    />
@endif
```

Please help.

I expected the images to show in the hosted application, as happens on my PC, or at least not to show at all, but instead they show under some circumstances.

Comment: Sounds like caching issue. I don't know how to solve in your stack, but you could check further towards this direction

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution:

This is what worked:

My application is in a subdomain.

Deleted 'storage' from the 'public_html' folder

Added a route like this to my route file web.php (Note the absolute path).

```
Route::get('/create-symlink', function () {
    symlink('/home/myusername/domains/mysub.domain.com/myappfolder/storage/app/public', '/home/myusername/domains/mysub.domain.com/public_html/storage');
    echo "Symlink Created. Thanks";
});
```

I then went to mysub.domain.com/create-symlink.

That was it!